# Is there a way in Eclipse to track recent SVN and CVS commits by author / username?

Tags: eclipse, svn, eclipse-plugin, cvs, commit

I am facing a very different issue due to the branches of source code.
I have 2 branches trunk and QA , because the source code is so huge its very difficult for me to remember all the files to checkin. 
I started monitoring my svn commit mails but thats not a very easy solution.
So I wanted to ask this question here.
Is there an Eclipse Plugin/Tool to keep track of SVN and CVS recent modified/commits?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Update 2: Search Subversion Commit History by Author / Username

Looks like there's a search history dialog built into the History view that allows to search by username.

[image]

### Update 1: Command Line Commit by Author / Username

To see recent commits for a specific user would the command line log command do it?

`svn log http://server/svn/foo -r 400:head | grep vince`

r400 | vince.eagen | 2012-12-03 09:02:50 -0800 (Mon, 03 Dec 2012) | 1 line

r422 | vince.eagen | 2012-12-03 15:37:20 -0800 (Mon, 03 Dec 2012) | 1 line

r424 | vince.eagen | 2012-12-03 15:44:07 -0800 (Mon, 03 Dec 2012) | 1 line

### Original Answer

Do you have [subclipse](http://subclipse.tigris.org/servlets/ProjectProcess?pageID=p4wYuA) installed?

If you right-click on a project or folder you can use `Team > Show History` to see a list of commits.

From there you can right-click and choose `Compare` to see the structure compare of each file.  Double-click on those and so-on and so-forth

[image]

There is also a `[CVS|SVN] Repository Exploring` perspective available in the `Window > Open Perspective > Other` if you prefer file explorer esque browsing.

Comment: Thank you i already know of these, I just want a list of commits by my userid or username. so that i can use the same list to merge into the QA tag repo